# How to access and pull files from a GIT repo from Jenkins using Git Deploy Key

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

We have an old Jenkins installation with a lot of other teams using them for their projects, therefore I cannot at the moment update it to a more recent version. I cannot use the Git-Jenkins plugins, and I am left with just using shell commands to try to pull/clone files from our Git repo. We already have created and enabled Deploy Keys on Git for Jenkins. As I am googling and testing shell command scripts to do the access and cloning of these files, I am wondering if anybody has experience or have already encountered the same problem and are willing to point me to the right direction on the proper script to use?

Comment: What problem you are exactly referring to?

Comment: This is my first time using shell commands to access a hosted repo, and I am looking for sample codes on how to do it, specifically commands to access Git. Please note that the Jenkins install we have, do not have (and I cannot install) any Git plugin installed.

Comment: So you basically need plain old git commands? Why not just looking into the git documentation https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: thanks mate, I did look into the link you gave and just used simple git commands to access and clone branches and tags. I didn't think it would be that simple (it was) that's why I decided on asking while at the same time experimenting :)

Comment: minimum requirement though is having Git in your Jenkins server, and adding and enabling a deploy key for Jenkins on Git.